# GCM update 7.5 to 8.3.0 fatal exception

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I tried to update the GCM services (Google cloud messages) libraries (from 7.5 to 8.3.0) in my Gradle project.
But now, with this new version, i'm unable to launch my previous activity which was working perfectly before.

The code which handle the following error is :

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, MyGcmListenerService.class);
startService(in);
```

MyGcmListenerService.java :

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "onMessageReceived");
    }
```

The returned error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Gradle files :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}
```

If I rollback to the previous GCM version (7.5) it's working back as expected.
Do you know what changed ? I checked the changelogs but I'm unable to found any informations about it.
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'd assume that you did a clean and rebuilt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try looking at the decompiled class file for `GcmListenerService` using your IDE.  When I do that with Android Studio for version 8.3.0, the code that appears to be throwing the exception is attempting to get the ACTION from the intent that invoked the service.  Because you are invoking the service with an explicit intent, the ACTION is null.

I'm wondering why you are invoking your subclass of `GcmListenerService` explicitly?  The normal GCM processing for message receipt is for the message to be delivered to `GcmReceiver`, which then passes it to the app's instance of `GcmListenerService` for processing.  You should not be invoking your listener service explicitly, `GcmReceiver` does that.  Take a look at the [sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart).

Comment: Thank you very much Qbix, It was a mistake from my side, I don't know why I called explicitly my GcmListener, probably an old part of my testing code ... you solved it ! Thank you :)

Comment: I am facing the same issue and the problem is when app is in background my service is not started. So I need to start it explicitly from broadcast receiver. What can I do in this case?