# GCM 8.3 - crash resulting from starting a GcmListenerService on ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I've inherited some code that invoked a GcmListenerService on ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:

```
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationListenerService.class));
    }
```

The purpose of this code was to make sure the GCM listener is initiated when the device boots up.

It has caused the crash described in [GCM update 7.5 to 8.3.0 fatal exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692070/gcm-update-7-5-to-8-3-0-fatal-exception):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

After I removed this code, as suggested in the accepted answer, everything works fine on my test device and my GCM listener is started when the device boots up as expected.

The question is whether there is a risk that for devices with a lower OS (I have Marshmallow on my test device) or play services version there might be a problem. If so, are there any possible ways to detect that and for those cases start the service?

Comment: you do not need to do this, GCM Messages get sent to a broadcast receiver in your app

Comment: @tyczj I understand that I don't need it for the latest version of GCM. The original code was written to overcome a problem in a previous GCM version. I am not sure if just deleting the code won't have negative side effects depending on the OS / Play Services version installed on different devices.

Comment: I have never heard of the broadcast receiver not being started. the broadcast receiver is declared in your manifest an it is always working per-say. I have done significant GCM work and never came across this problem. It looks like you are trying to do something that is undocumented so I would expect it to break like it did. Even the answer in your link says not to do this

Comment: As I said in the question - "I've inherited some code"... so I am trying to make sure that there are no risks to doing the right thing and deleting it. Thanks @tyczj.

Comment: I know and I am saying I have never come across this issue and I would delete it. if there are problem getting messages typically the problem is outside your app ie. user intervention, server issue or other external issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling and testing I decided to delete this piece of code. I saw no negative effect. The original intention of this code was to overcome a GCM bug that caused the listener not to start automatically. However with version 8.3 this approach is wrong and should be removed as it causes crashes on some devices.